# How to handle this curve?

Tags: parametric, curves

I started with differentiation of all three coordinates of this parametrically given curve.

I want to show that the respective curve has related equation of the plane and also to prove that it a "plane-curve".

$$\gamma\left(t\right)=\left(\frac{1+t^2}t\;,\;{t+1}\;,\;\frac{1-t}t\right)$$

Comment: What does "andle" mean?

Comment: this is your 7th post. you should start to write you formulas in LaTeX

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x(t)-z(t)=y(t)$, which implies that the curve lies in the plane $x-y-z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that torsion is null. You can see the formules [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve)

Comment: Alternatively, compute the binormal vector and check that it is constant.